# SCNNode with constant scale from any camera position in SceneKit

Tags: swift, 3d, scenekit

I want to implement a `SCNNode` (backed by geometry) that stays a constant scale from any camera position (even when zooming in or out). Examples of these types of objects are in the `SceneKit` Editor such as the camera or 3D manipulator. Zooming closer to these objects doesn't change the size they appear. Similar to how an `MKAnnotation` works on a `MapView`. I would imagine that you have to modify the scale each time the camera position changes but I'm not sure how to pull this off.

Answer (score 2):

Would it work for you to use an orthographic projection on your camera? That will make each node constant size, regardless of varying distance from camera.

Something like

```
view.pointOfView.usesOrthographicProjection = true
```

(`pointOfView` being an `SCNCamera`)

If you want only *some* nodes to be fixed size, then yes, you will need to rescale the node as the camera moves. You might be able to do this with a shader fragment, or maybe a Core Image filter.